# Copy all highlighted text in Preview

Tags: macos, preview

I have a book I'm reading in Preview (PDF) and I had highlighted some vocabs. I would like to copy those vocabs into an excel sheet. Is there anyway to do this without manually copying them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately exporting highlights in bulk is not implemented in Apple Preview (yet).

What you can do:

- Show all notes and annotations from preview in a list like [this](https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/highlight-underline-and-strike-out-text-prvw757d4d5b/mac) (press option+cmd+4). But you'd still need to copy them manually. With this list you just get an overview and can jump directly to them within Preview.
- Try the App [Highlights](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/highlights-export-pdf-notes/id1498912833), which provides your desired functionality. I doubt it can read the highlights from preview though. Might still be worth a try to verify if it works for you and if you want to use it for this functionality in the future.